# Android: Wakeup or Relaunch app when Home Button Pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I am working on the Kiosk mode in Android using the following link and would control the "onBackPressed" and "Switch App" icon.

http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

**What I want**
When users press the home button, the app will just "wake-up" or relaunch instead of the activity is closing down.

I am able to detech when home button is pressed and I ask the app to wakeup, but the app is still leaving when home button is pressed.

Comment: Can you declare your app as a launcher? Then it would just open itself and you wouldn't need anything special.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are developing for Android 6.0 or greater, look at this site: https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html . Google may have started preventing the disabling of the home button sometime after Android 4.